# R function select value in vector via input value and between values other vector

Tags: r

I am not sure if I explain this correctly... but I have a function with 3 vectors and a value input, where the value of vector 3 (`val_3`) needs to be selected based on the input value which is between the values in vector 1 (`val_1`) and 2 (`val_2`)... How do I do this?

```
val <- 235412
  
select <- function(val){
  
  val_1 <- c(1, 10, 100, 10000, 100000)
  val_2 <- c(10, 100, 10000, 100000, 1000000)
  val_3 <- c(2:6)
  
  for (i in length(val_1)) {
    
    if (val > val_1[i] && val < val_2[i]){
      select_var = val_3[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Wouldn't you just find the ceiling value of the log or the length of the string representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your example is over-simplified and the vectors involved aren't always powers of 10, you can avoid a loop altogether by using the fact that R is vectorized:

```r
select <- function(val) {
  
  val_1 <- c(1, 10, 100, 10000, 100000)
  val_2 <- c(10, 100, 10000, 100000, 1000000)
  val_3 <- c(2:6)
  
  val_3[which(val_1 < val & val_2 > val)]
  
}

select(235412)
#> [1] 6
```

If your variables inside the function never change, you could even shorten the function to:

```r
select <- function(val) (2:6)[tail(which(log(val, 10) > (0:6)[-4]), 1)]

select(235412)
#> [1] 6
```

But this is difficult to read and hence would be difficult to debug.

As a side-note here, it would be best not to call your function `select`, as there are already commonly used functions called `select` that this would over-write.